# jquery lightbox inline - without popup

Tags: jquery, lightbox

i like [jquery lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) control looks nice and shows me a title one 1 of x images etc. I need exactly the same thing but without pop up. So whas is now visible after i click thumnail of image i want it to by visible as inline content somewhere on my page with first image loaded and then i could just use next prev. of course in this case, close would not be applicable. Does anybode know such a jquery plugin or how to change lightbox to work withoud popup? Thanks.